# zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord returned object get data

Tags: php, zoho, zcrmsdk

Using this awesome [package](https://github.com/asciisd/zoho), I'm having trouble on how to get the actual value from the returned data from ZohoCRM. Here's an example:

Using dd():

```php
zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord {#1 ▼
  -entityId: "111"
  -moduleApiName: "Leads"
  -lineItems: []
  -lookupLabel: null
}
```

Using var_dump():

```php
object(zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord)#111 (4) {
  ["entityId":"zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord":private]=>
  string(3) "111"
  ["moduleApiName":"zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord":private]=>
  string(5) "Leads"
  ["lineItems":"zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["lookupLabel":"zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

Here's the code in getting the data:

```php
$records = ZohoManager::useModule('Leads')->searchRecordsByWord('word to be searched');

$first_record = $records[0];
```

I would like to know how to get the specific value like entityId? Thank you.

Comment: That package seems to be a wrapper for [this package](https://github.com/zoho/zcrm-php-sdk) (where the class `ZCRMRecord` comes from). Looking at that readme, it seems that they have getters for those private values, like: `$first_record->getEntityId()` and so on. You can see all available methods in that class: https://github.com/zoho/zcrm-php-sdk/blob/master/src/crm/crud/ZCRMRecord.php